# i3 config issue

Tags: configuration, i3-wm

I'm currently getting to grips with i3 and everything is going fine so far but I can't seem to move i3bar to the top of my screen rather than the bottom.

I've added this line to the i3 config file

bar {

> position top

}

And after this i restarted i3 wiht Mod+shift+r but it doesn't move at all.

Can anyone lend a hand on this?

Comment: Are you editing the i3status config, `~/.config/i3status/config`? or the i3 config `~/.i3/config`?

Comment: I was using '~/.config/i3status/config' I've switched to '~/.i3/config' now aaaaand it works.

Comment: Well, good luck :)